# How can I hook mapped drive (Z: -> \\myserver\share) turn disconnected?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, networking

I have several network drives connected to my PC.
How can my application (VC++/Win32) on this PC, hook or get event when user disconnect drive?
(Right click menu, Disconnect item).

Thank a lot,
Dmitry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should have a listener that would catch this event. You can use  WNetGetConnection and check for the return code. Here's the link where you could find details about this method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385453.aspx